# add next button in conditional question answer form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a next button in a webpage where the displayed question depends on the previous answers. In the following you can see my DOM elements and the conditional questions are nested in an click event handler, as below. How can I add a next button, that navigates the user to the previous question?

```js
$(".btn-answer")
.off("click")
.on("click", function (evt) {
  var answer = $(this).attr("value");

  if (answer == "yes") {
    $(".question1").hide();
    $(".question2").show();

    $(".button2").click(function () {
      var answer2 = $(this).attr("value");

      if (answer2 == "slight") {
        $(".question2").hide();
        $(".question4").show();
      }
      if (answer2 == "moderate") {
        $(".question2").hide();
        $(".question4").show();
      }
      if (answer2 == "heavy") {
        $(".question2").hide();
        $(".question4").show();
      }
    });
  } else if (answer == "no") {
    console.log("no damage");
  }
$(".btn-answer")
.off("click")
.on("click", function (evt) {
  var answer = $(this).attr("value");

  if (answer == "yes") {
    $(".question1").hide();
    $(".question2").show();

    $(".button2").click(function () {
      var answer2 = $(this).attr("value");

      if (answer2 == "slight") {
        $(".question2").hide();
        $(".question4").show();
      }
      if (answer2 == "moderate") {
        $(".question2").hide();
        $(".question4").show();
      }
      if (answer2 == "heavy") {
        $(".question2").hide();
        $(".question4").show();
      }
    });
  } else if (answer == "no") {
    console.log("no damage");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question1">
  <h2 id="question1">Do you see any damage?</h2>
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-answer" value="yes" id="yes">Yes</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-answer" value="no" id="no">No</button>
</div>

<div class="question2" style="display: none">
  <h2 id="question2">What is the degree of damage?</h2>
  <button class="button2" value="slight" id="slight">slight</button>
  <button class="button2" value="moderate" id="moderate">moderate</button>
  <button class="button2" value="heavy" id="heavy">heavy</button>
</div>

<div class="question3" style="display: none">
  <h2 id="question3">What material can you see?</h2>
  <button class="button3" value="masonry" id="masonry">masonry</button>
  <button class="button3" value="concrete" id="concrete">concrete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to get the data of question-answer like result=[{q1:"des",ans:yes}]?

Comment: yes! I want to save it in an array afterwards.

Comment: you can this> https://jsfiddle.net/gp0b3qv7/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. When you will click the Get Summary it will show the result.
After every click, I have stored the information in the array and show it at the end.

```js
let questionSheet=[];

$(document).ready(function (){
$(".ans1").on("click", function (){
                    var answer = $(this).attr("value"); 
          if (answer == "yes") {
            $(".question1").hide();
            $(".question2").show();           
          } else if (answer == "no") {
            console.log("no damage");
          };
          
          questionSheet.push({id:1,question:"Do you see any damage?",ans:answer});
});

 $(".ans2").click(function () {
              var answer2 = $(this).attr("value");

              if (answer2 == "slight") {
                $(".question2").hide();
                $(".question4").show();
              }
              if (answer2 == "moderate") {
                $(".question2").hide();
                $(".question4").show();
              }
              if (answer2 == "heavy") {
                $(".question2").hide();
                $(".question4").show();
              }
                            
               questionSheet.push({id:2,question:"What is the degree of damage?",ans:answer2});
            });
            
         $(".ans3").on("click", function (){
           var answer3 = $(this).attr("value");
           
            questionSheet.push({id:3,question:"What material can you see?",ans:answer3});
         });




});

function fnGetSummary(){
console.log(questionSheet);

let result=questionSheet.map(r=>`Q.${r.id} - Question : ${r.question} Answer: ${r.ans}`).join("<br/>");

$("#answer").html(result);
}
```

```html
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question1">
    <h2 id="question1">Do you see any damage?</h2>
    <button class="btn btn-success ans1" value="yes" id="yes">Yes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success ans1" value="no" id="no">No</button>
  </div>

  <div class="question2" style="display: none">
    <h2 id="question2">What is the degree of damage?</h2>
    <button class="ans2" value="slight" id="slight">slight</button>
    <button class="ans2" value="moderate" id="moderate">moderate</button>
    <button class="ans2" value="heavy" id="heavy">heavy</button>
  </div>

  <div class="question3" style="display: none">
    <h2 id="question3">What material can you see?</h2>
    <button class="ans3" value="masonry" id="masonry">masonry</button>
    <button class="ans3" value="concrete" id="concrete">concrete</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="question4" style="display: none">Question 4</div>
  
  <button onclick="fnGetSummary()">Get Summary</button>
  
  <div id="answer"></div>
```

Comment: this is helpful for me, but how can I embed a next button in this logic?

Comment: The next button will be enabled / visible after the click the last question.

Comment: i see. is there also an option with a previous button to display the previous question?

Comment: Right now if you click the summary btn then summary will be visible in DOM you can call this review. After showing the summary you can add another btn called submit to submit the information to the server.

Comment: yes, but what is if I have answered my first question and want to change it. Is there an option to click on a "previous" button to get to my first question, so that I can change it

Comment: okay, just I will remake this page, How many questions available there?

Comment: I have a list of 10-15 questions depending on previous answer :/. in this example I just showed the first three questions if yes clicked --> display: slight, moderate, heavy ---> if slight clicked --> display: what material can you see? ---> and so on ...